# Why is this integral on finite measure finite?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(X) < \infty$. Suppose that $\mu$ attains finitely many values ('$\mu$ is finitely supported').

Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ a measurable function. Can we deduce that

$$\int_X f d \mu$$

exists?

I guess this should be easy: maybe show it first for indicator functions, then positive functions and then general measurable functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu$ is supported by $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ then $\int_X fd\mu=\sum \int _{\{x_i\}} fd\mu=\sum f(x_i) \mu ({\{x_i\}})$.

I have used the following facts: the integral of any measurable function over a set of measure  $0$ exists and equals $0$. (Take the set of measure $0$ as the complement of the support of $\mu$). If $f$ has a constant value  $c$ on a set $A$ then $\int_A fd\mu= c\mu(A)$.